# Cut command shortcut problem

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

I cannot find the way to change the key shortcut for cut command on my macBook pro.

Where can I change that setting?

I can't find it with the rest of the key command preferences.

Answer (score 2):

On my machine, the following works:

Go to System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Application Shortcuts. Press the [+] button. Select All Applications, type Cut, press your shortcut, and press <kbd>Add</kbd>.

Note that on systems still running OS X 10.8 and earlier, it's: System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Application Shortcuts

[image]

Comment: afraid this doesnt work

Comment: What do you mean with OMM? Is it the same as OMOM?